# Blurring background when React portal is displayed

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, modal-dialog

I'm using React portals to create a modal popup after form submission. I would like to blur just the background and to show the modal like in picture 2. I used `document.body.style.filter = "blur(5px)` in the first picture but it blurs everything.
CSS for the modal and modal root (my code is almost identical to the React docs for portals)

````
```
#modal-root {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}
.modal {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 99999;
}```
````

[image: What I have so far]

[image: what I want it to look like]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every child of the element that you blur will have that filter applied. Since you have similar code to the portal docs then im going to assume your html structure is something like this

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="app-root"></div>
    <div id="modal-root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

if this is the case then apply the filter to app-root aka...

```
document.getElementById('app-root').style.filter = 'blur(5px)'
```

Comment: Thank you! Of course that's the one element I didn't try to filter. Not sure if this is the best way to remove the filter on exit of the modal.
    ```document.getElementById('app-root').style.filter = 'blur(0px) grayscale(0%)'``` but, it works.

Comment: Happy to help! :) And Yes that is a completely fine way to apply the filter, you may also be able to just set the filter to none

Comment: I tried using 'none' in Chrome dev tools but, it didn't like it. 0px seems to work fine. Thank you again.

Answer (score 7):

Because your modal has fixed position, when your modal is open, to blur the background, add

```
  backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
```

or

```
  backdropFilter: blur(8px);
```

to the style of your modal body and that should do the job.

Comment: Correct, this is a much easier solution

Answer (score -1):

Can you wrap the body in an outter div, then blur that making sure your modal is outside your "blur" div?

Comment: I did try that. I ended up basically walking down the DOM tree in Dev tool and adding blur to every element one by one to see which element I had to target to get the desired effect. I must have missed the root element because that was the only one that worked for me.